# sed wildcards for any number

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace the string "samples : [any number] failing samples : [any number] with the string 'OK' using sed.

This works with single digits. However, I need an option for any number:

```
sed 's/samples : [0-9] failing samples : [0-9]/OK/g' ./sedTest.txt
```

Before Data:

```
10,foo,bar,samples : 9 failing samples : 7,bar,next Item
10,foo,bar,samples : 99 failing samples : 55,bar,next Item
10,foo,bar,samples : 9229 failing samples : 5225,bar,next Item
```

I'm trying to achieve this..

```
10,foo,bar,OK,bar,next Item
10,foo,bar,OK,bar,next Item
10,foo,bar,OK,bar,next Item
```

Comment: Add a quantifier to the character class, e.g. `[0-9]\+`

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Thor, you can use "\+" to greedily swallow all occurrences:

```
sed 's/samples : [0-9]\+ failing samples : [0-9]\+/OK/g' ./sedTest.txt
```

But it is more common to use "*":

```
sed 's/samples : [0-9]* failing samples : [0-9]*/OK/g' ./sedTest.txt
```

Eg. for the following output:

```
cat sedTest.txt; echo "Replace numbers..."; sed 's/samples : [0-9]* failing samples : [0-9]*/OK/g' ./sedTest.txt
10,foo,bar,samples : 9 failing samples : 7,bar,next Item
10,foo,bar,samples : 99 failing samples : 55,bar,next Item
10,foo,bar,samples : 9229 failing samples : 5225,bar,next Item

Replace numbers...
10,foo,bar,OK,bar,next Item
10,foo,bar,OK,bar,next Item
10,foo,bar,OK,bar,next Item
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed `[0-9]` will only match a single digit. To match more digits, it is necessary to add a quantifier. Since you want "one or more" digits, simply add a `+` character after the bracket. It will greedily match all characters inside the brackets (in this case, any digits).

```
sed 's/samples : [0-9]+ failing samples : [0-9]+/OK/g' ./sedTest.txt
```

Depending on which system you are using, it is possible you need to run `sed` with either the `-r` flag (linux) or `-E` flag (mac). This is to allow for modern regex symbols like `+`.

Alternatively, instead of using `+`, use `*`. This will match "zero or more" instead of "one or more" occurrences. The advantage here is that no flag is required.